# How could I run a function after the completion of a for loop in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say if I have a structure in Node.js shown below:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    //Doing a for loop.
}

function after_forloop() {
    //Doing a function.
}

after_forloop();
```

So how could I make sure the after_forloop() function is fired after the forloop is completed?

In case if you want to see what I am actually working on:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

var proxyChecker = require('proxy-checker');
var fs = require('fs');

function get_line(filename, line_no, callback) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var lines = data.toString('utf-8').split("\n");
        var firstLineBreak = data.toString('utf-8').indexOf("\n");
        var originalText = data.toString('utf-8');
        var newText = originalText.substr(firstLineBreak + 1);
        if(+line_no > lines.length){
            return callback('File end reached without finding line', null);
        }

        callback(null, lines[+line_no], newText);
    });
}


for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    get_line('proxy_full.txt', i, function(err, line, newText){
        fs.appendFile('proxy.txt', line + '\n', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;         
        });     
        fs.writeFile('proxy_full.txt', newText, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    })
}

after_forloop();

function after_forloop() {
    proxyChecker.checkProxiesFromFile(
        // The path to the file containing proxies
        'proxy.txt',
        {
            // the complete URL to check the proxy
            url: 'http://google.com',   
            // an optional regex to check for the presence of some text on the page
            regex: /.*/
        },
        // Callback function to be called after the check
        function(host, port, ok, statusCode, err) {
            if (ok) {
                console.log(host + ':' + port);
                fs.appendFile('WorkingProxy.txt', host + ':' + port + '\n', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;             
                });
            }                   
        }
    );

    setTimeout(function(){
        fs.writeFile('proxy.txt', "", function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        console.log('Proxy Check Completed.')
        process.exit(1); 
    }, 5000);
}
```

Basically I like to allow the node server run 50 test on a list proxy servers at a time (within five seconds). And then the server should save the working proxies to a new file.

Comment: Execute it after the loop? Note you forgot to declare `i`.

Comment: By "after the `for` loop is completed" you probably mean "after all the asynchronous activity started in the `for` loop is completed", right?

Comment: I'm not getting what special here, just call that after `for` loop finished.

Comment: code usually runs top-down, but if it's not, you can make sure _i_ is 50...

Comment: can you show the content of `for` loop.

Comment: Not quite sure exactly what you are asking here, but in async cases sometimes these are useful for avoiding "*callback hell*":  https://github.com/caolan/async  -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/21184964/103081

Comment: just post full code, as you have mentioned in comments at answer, writing to file is a `async` task if you are not using a `sync` function. That's why you are facing strange behaviour.

Comment: @Mritunjay I just did! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
var operationsCompleted = 0;
function operation() {
    ++operationsCompleted;
    if (operationsCompleted === 100) after_forloop(); 
}
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    get_line('proxy_full.txt', i, function(err, line, newText){
        fs.appendFile('proxy.txt', line + '\n', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            operation();
        });     
        fs.writeFile('proxy_full.txt', newText, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            operation();
        });
    })
}
```

Admittedly this isn't an elegant solution. If you're doing a whole lot of this you might want to check out something like [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 9):

If you're doing any async operation in the for loop, you can simply keep it like

```
function after_forloop() {
// task you want to do after for loop finishes it's execution
}


 for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
 //Doing a for loop.

 if(i == 49) {
  after_forloop() // call the related function
 }
}
```

Still in node.js, instead of making use of for loops with asynchronous functions, you should see the async module. Here's [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async.git) or you can consider using recursion too.

Answer (score 8):

If there is no magic happening then it should be straight forword.

Function:-

```
function after_forloop() {
    //Doing a function.
}
```

For Loop:-

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    //Doing a for loop.
}
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    //Doing another for loop.
}
after_forloop();
```

This will call `after_forloop` just after both `for` loops finishes. Because `for` loop is a blocking call, calling of `after_forloop()` has to wait.

**Note:-** If you are doing some `async` task in `for` loops then the function will be called after loop finished, but the work you are doing in loops might not finished by the time of calling function.

Comment: Great! What happen if I have multiple for loops, will it wait for all the for loops to complete?

Comment: @AeroWindwalker Yes the line will be called after `for` loop finished, because `for` loop is a sync task, it will blocking.

Comment: I think Nodejs isn't letting for loop running as a sync task. For example if I let the for loop to create a file with 50 lines, then having a function output the file, it will only output 1 or 2 lines (sometimes no line at all).

Comment: @AeroWindwalker you should probably forgot to read the `note` part of answer. I told you if you are doing some `async` task in `for` loop that might not finished.

Comment: Interesting! What would be the solution to it if I am doing asyn tasks in the forloop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68696/discussion-between-aero-windwalker-and-mritunjay).

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the last iteration of the for loop with a conditional checking index.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(i == 10 - 1){
    your_function();
  }
}
```

Comment: I use this pattern, it works well. Also, I can make it dynamic with array.length.

Answer (score 2):

use the Async module, Its easy and best.

```
async.each(array, function (element, callback) {
                        callback()
                    }, async function (err) {
                       console.log("array ends")
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one!

```
try {
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    //Doing a for loop.
  }
} finally {
  after_forloop();
}
```