# How to capture local variable value on asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, variables, asynchronous, callback, anonymous-function

I have this `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
{
   var character = characters[i];
   charService.get(character.name).then(function (characterData)
   {
        //I want character to be captured here, i.e. the character in the current loop
        character.data = characterData;
   });
}
```

As `charService.get()` is asynchronous, by the time the callback is executed, `character` is the last element of the array (because the loop has ended), hence all the previous `character` are left alone with no data.

How can I guarantee that `character.data` inside the callback is referencing the `character` of the loop the asynchronous method was executed?

Comment: use iffy and passing parameters will make it persist it

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184340/async-for-loop-in-node-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Function.prototype.bind()` at `.then()` function , set to `character`

```
for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
{
   var character = characters[i];
   charService.get(character.name).then(function (characterData)
   {
        //I want character to be captured here, i.e. the character in the current loop
        this.data = characterData;
   }.bind(character));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it into function

```
for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
{
   (function(character){
   charService.get(character.name).then(function (characterData)
   {
        //I want character to be captured here, i.e. the character in the current loop
        character.data = characterData;
   });
   })(characters[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution! Very creative!