# Node JS loop and callback

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, node-rest-client

I'm using `node-rest-client` to make a GET call to an endpoint, and would like to make this call multiple times (in a loop), then expose a parameter of the response.
The code looks like:

```
// registering remote methods
client.registerMethod("reflect", "<the URL>", "GET");
// call the method
var i = 10;
while (i>0) {
    client.methods.reflect(function (data, response) {
        console.log("x-forwarded-for: " + data.headers["x-forwarded-for"]);
        // raw response
        //console.log(response);
      });
    i--;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x-forwarded-for' of undefined
```

If `i` is equal to 2, then this is OK.
I suppose the issue comes from the fact that this is asynchronous execution and all the calls in the while are fired at once, resulting into some clogging somewhere along the lines.

What is the best way of having a synchronous execution (assuming this is where the problem lies)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async for loop in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184340/async-for-loop-in-node-js)

Comment: You can use control flow library like `async`, or use recursion to do that. Promises also would work.

Comment: Thanks - yes, just saw this which I believe does solve the problem: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#whilst

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check  x-forwarded-for lies in response and if the same problem persists as you are expecting(asynchronous call) then
just wrap this call inside a anonymous function like this

```
while(i > 0) {
    (function abc(){
        client.methods.reflect(function (data, response) {
            console.log("x-forwarded-for: " + data.headers["x-forwarded-for"]);
            // raw response
            //console.log(response);
        });
    }())

    i--;
}
```

Comment: There is no point in wrapping. Inside callback function i variable is not used.

Comment: then just remove this i variable,it doesn't matter