# How to use async functions in for loop with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I'm building a web scraper using Nodejs and I use a lot of asynchronous functions which I have written. I want to run a chain of functions using different page ids but for loop doesn't seem to work properly. I tried using counter variables too but it doesn't produce required results.. Please find my code below:

```
var pageInformation = [
['page1','id111'],
['page2','id222'],
['page3','id333']];

var reqCounter = 0;

for(page in pageInformation){
    var pageName = pageInformation[reqCounter][0];
    var pageId = pageInformation[reqCounter][1]
    getPosts(pageId,function(err,idArray){
        if(!err){
            getMoreData(idArray, function(data,err){
                if(!err){
                    populateDatabase(data, function(err,success){
                        if(!err){
                        reqCounter++;
                            console.log('Loop for ' + pageName + 'has finished');//prints out page1 three times 
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })    
}
```

What happens is console.log() prints out page1 three times and and database gets populated with the first page data only. Any ideas on how I could run this chain of code for each of the pages in the pagesInformation array?

Comment: 1. Don't use `for...in` with arrays. 2. Checkout the `for (await x of y)` syntax.

Comment: `reqCounter++` isn't run when you think it runs. Look into `Promise.all()`. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184340/async-for-loop-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop runs synchronously, while your `reqCounter` is only incremented when each of the asynchronous calls have finished. This means that `reqCounter` will still be `0` in each iteration.

Furthermore, variables declared with `var` are not block scoped but scoped to the current function. This means that `pageName` and `pageId` will be reassigned in each iteration rather than each iteration having its own version of the variables.

The latter issue can be solved by declaring those variables with `let` or `const` as this makes them block scoped, i.e. each iteration gets its own version. Since you never reassign them, `const` is appropriate.

For the first issue, I can't see why you need the `reqCounter` in the first place. Just use the iterator variable `page`.

Finally, it's a bad idea to use a `for...in` loop on arrays as that can easily cause bugs and unexpected behavior. You should use `for...of` or `forEach()` instead.

So, my solution for your problem would be to change these three lines:

```
for(page in pageInformation){
    var pageName = pageInformation[reqCounter][0];
    var pageId = pageInformation[reqCounter][1]
```

into this:

```
for (const page of pageInformation) {
    const pageName = page[0];
    const pageId = page[1];
```